# docker login fails with cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type configfile.ConfigFile

Tags: docker

I just installed 19.03.2 on my windows 10 laptop. When I attempt any docker command such as docker login or docker version, I get the warning as below.

WARNING: Error loading config file: C:\Users\user-id.docker\config.json: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type configfile.ConfigFile

My config.json looks as below

```
"quay.io": {"<hidden for security reasons>"}
```

Could not find any reference to error for docker login in google search. There are reference for type string, but not for configfile.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear the file, delete everything in: `C:\Users\user-id.docker\config.json`
2. From the command line run:

```
docker login -u your_docker_username "https://index.docker.io/v1/"
```

3. Type your password

Output:
`Login Succeeded`

It will generate "auths" credentials in `C:\Users\user-id.docker\config.json` file

You can use `dokcer login` again with no problems after that